# Python: return nested dict of values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I'm typing 3 list of loops, and I need return dict like in docstring. And it's wrong. How can I solve problem?

For each period you have to count incomes and expenses and total occurrence.

2. Changes out of functions body are not allowed.
3. Additional imports are not allowed.
4. Data could have wholes in periods range ex. 2022-01,2022-03 (missing February), then we assume that item has 0 documents in period

Sample of dict looks like below:

```
   [
    {
        "package": "FLEXIBLE",
        "created": "2020-03-10T00:00:00",
        "summary": [
            {
                "period": "2019-12",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 63,
                    "expenses": 13
                }
            },
            {
                "period": "2020-02",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 45,
                    "expenses": 81
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "package": "ENTERPRISE",
        "created": "2020-03-19T00:00:00",
        "summary": [
            {
                "period": "2020-01",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 15,
                    "expenses": 52
                }
            },
            {
                "period": "2020-02",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 76,
                    "expenses": 47
                }
            }
        ]
    }
   ]
```

Code for the task is here:

```
def task_2(data_in):
    '''
        Return number of documents per period (incomes, expenses, total).
        ex. {
            '2020-04': {
                'incomes': 2480,
                'expenses': 2695,
                'total': 5175
            },
            '2020-05': {
                'incomes': 2673,
                'expenses': 2280,
                'total': 4953
            }
        }
    '''
    period = []
    for term in data_in:
        for dict_val in term['summary']:
            if dict_val['period'] in period:
                continue
            else:
                period.append(dict_val['period'])

    incomes = []
    for term in data_in:
        for dict_val in term['summary']:
            incomes.append(dict_val['documents']['incomes'])

    expenses = []
    for term in data_in:
        for dict_val in term['summary']:
            expenses.append(dict_val['documents']['expenses'])

    # dict_keys = ['incomes', 'expenses', 'total']
    # list1 = [{k: v for k, v in zip(dict_keys, range(len(incomes)))}]

    # return {k: v for k, v in zip(period, list1)}
    return {per: {"incomes": inc, "expenses": exp, "total": inc + exp} for per, inc, exp in
            zip(period, range(len(incomes)), range(len(expenses)))}
```

I'm typing loops in dict but returns:

```
{'2019-12': {'incomes': 1, 'expenses': 1, 'total': 2},
 '2020-02': {'incomes': 2, 'expenses': 2, 'total': 4}}
```

Comment: this is python language, do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: this include income expense for both package type ?

Comment: Yes, we're supposed to group it by period, not by package type

Comment: the point is that for each period, it counts the sum of "incomes", "expenses" and "total", grouped by periods and returns how many times "expenses" or "incomes" appeared for a given period

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to track the period and save income, expenses, total

```
data = [
    {
        "package": "FLEXIBLE",
        "created": "2020-03-10T00:00:00",
        "summary": [
            {
                "period": "2019-12",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 63,
                    "expenses": 13
                }
            },
            {
                "period": "2020-02",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 45,
                    "expenses": 81
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "package": "ENTERPRISE",
        "created": "2020-03-19T00:00:00",
        "summary": [
            {
                "period": "2020-01",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 15,
                    "expenses": 52
                }
            },
            {
                "period": "2020-02",
                "documents": {
                    "incomes": 76,
                    "expenses": 47
                }
            }
        ]}]


records = [record for records in data for record in records['summary']  ]

result =  {}
template = {
        "incomes": 0,
        "expenses": 0,
        "total": 0
    }
for record in records:
    period = record['period']
    if period not in result:
        result[period] = {"incomes": 0,"expenses": 0,"total": 0}
    income = record['documents']['incomes']
    expense = record['documents']['expenses']
    total = income + expense

    result[period]['incomes'] += income
    result[period]['expenses'] += expense
    result[period]['total'] += total


print(result)

# output -> {'2019-12': {'incomes': 63, 'expenses': 13, 'total': 76}, '2020-02': {'incomes': 121, 'expenses': 128, 'total': 249}, '2020-01': {'incomes': 15, 'expenses': 52, 'total': 67}}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I only have 2 years of Python experience, self taught, so I seek help on forums for books, courses, etc. If I had commercial experience, things would be different. Thank you very much for help :) !!!

Comment: @MarekGrzesiak the outout is same as expected by the function, maybe you can try to debug where it is getting wrong

Comment: sahasrara62 I solved problem sorry about that, I was wrong. Luck of experience. Sorry :)

Comment: Your solution is wrong. I'm expecting not a sum of values, I'm expecting a count of how many times an instance occurred, like 'incomes': appeared: 2480

Comment: @MarekGrzesiak add a counter to count that, if condition: count+= 1

Comment: Income_count+=1, if 'income' in record['documents']: income_count+=1, maybe ask a new question and explain what u want and what u understood and where u stuck, this way you will learn

Comment: Your solution is good!!! sorry about mistakes :)

Comment: Can You help me with Task: 3. Here is a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75690693/iterate-through-jsone-file-in-python

Answer (score 3):

You can solve that by creating a dict that has the period as key and a dict with the sums of `incomes`, `expenses` and `total` as value for every key. The structure will be this:

```py
result = dict(
    '2019-12' = dict(
      'incomes' = 0,
      'expenses' = 0,
      'total' = 0,
    ),
    '2020-01' = dict(
      'incomes' = 0,
      'expenses' = 0,
      'total' = 0,
    )
)
```

But you will instantiate as an empty `dict` at first, and will populate it as you iterate over the data.

```py
result = dict()
# or simply: result = {}
```

You will iterate over every `term['summary']` in every `term`, in `data_in`, as you are already doing with

```py
for term in data_in:
    for dict_val in term['summary']:
```

Once you have the data to be processed, you need to check if the period of the current `dict_val` already exists in the `result` dict. If not, create it with initial values:

```py
if dict_val['period'] not in result:
    result[dict_val['period']] = {'incomes': 0, 'expenses': 0, 'total': 0}
```

then, you proceed with doing the calculations for the current `dict_val`:

```py
result[dict_val['period']]['incomes'] += dict_val['incomes']
result[dict_val['period']]['expenses'] += dict_val['expenses']
result[dict_val['period']]['total'] += dict_val['incomes'] + dict_val['expenses']
```

Once the iteration is over, you will have your `result` variable with the data you need

Comment: I can't reach a solution, it's makes errors like: KeyError: 'incomes'